# Function Declaration and definition

Tags: python

What are my errors in this function declaration and definition?

```
greeting = "Hello CSCI141!
modifiedGreeting = 'h' + greeting(1:)
modifiedGreeting = ModifiedGreeting.lower
print("Original greeting" + greeting
print(modifiedGreeting)
```

Comment: Terminate the strings correctly. And check your variable spellings. BTW, this is not a function. What language is that?

Comment: The language this is Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be here.

```
modifiedGreeting = ModifiedGreeting.lower
```

I believe you have the wrong case.It should be

```
modifiedGreeting.lower
```

Also, you haven't closed the quote on the first line.

Also, to select a part of the string, you used the `[]` brackets, not `()`

Finally, the bracket on the second last `print` statement, was not closed.

The working code being:

```
greeting = "Hello CSCI141!"
modifiedGreeting = 'h' + greeting[1:]
modifiedGreeting = modifiedGreeting.lower()
print("Original: " +greeting)
print(modifiedGreeting)
```

Here is the [working demo](https://ideone.com/Zmwb5Q)

Comment: greeting = "Hello CSCI141!"
    modifiedGreeting = 'h' + greeting(1:)
    modifiedGreeting.lower
    print("Original greeting" + greetingprint(modifiedGreeting)

Comment: sorry I am having trouble with formatting in the comments. can you write it to exactly how I am supposed to write the code?

Comment: Hi, please check the demo link, it should be working fine

Comment: Original Hello CSCI141!
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x000000A410A41970>

Comment: This is the output I got. Is this supposed to be correct?

Comment: Please check the link again, I have updated the function to ensure you get a lowercase output.Here is the [link](https://ideone.com/Zmwb5Q)

Comment: You probably want to *call* `lower` -- i.e., `modifiedGreeting.lower()`

Comment: Yes, i did that in the link!I'll update the code here too, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote/select it as an answer if you're satisfied. @m.daoo